# Split on " " except when a certain collection of words follow

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to make an acronym splitter. The idea being, if I'm fed the string "United States of America" I will get back an array of three strings, "United", "States of", "America".

I will then display them stacked vertically with the first letters bolded as such:

**U** nited

**S** tates of

**A** merica

What's a good way to do this? I assume it involves some kind of split, and a string array containing common words to leave out, like "of, a, if, then" etc...

Comment: Seems more like you'll want to do a regex to do the initial split, and then process it from there.

Comment: @Gjeltema that's probably true, just not sure how to use Regex with a string array that's an exception list

Comment: Alternatively, you just loop through and manually process.  Do a split on the " ", and then as you iterate over the list, do a "peek" at the next index to see if the value is contained in your "exceptions" list.  If it does, then splice the two values together, and move on.  More code, but probably more readable than the regex for this.  I can throw up some sample stub code if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: IS the first letter of the word you're trying to highlight always upper case? similarly, is the first letter of the words you're trying to 'ignore' always lower case?

Comment: @Polity +1. Why not just split by first letter uppercase?

Comment: @Polity because this is a user entered field, and that would mean this always failed unless a user did it correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use such regex for that:

```
Regex.Split(str, " (?!of|a|if)");
```

Live demo: http://ideone.com/KdQnfZ

As community proposes in the comments - you might split by a space followed by a word started with a capital letter like

```
Regex.Split(str, " (?=[A-Z])")
```

Comment: Looks awesome. I might keep a separate string list to edit easily, and build the expression with a string.format or some such function.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use regex an expression like `([a-zA-Z]+ ?(of|in|and)?)` will work as long as the inner group (the of in and one) is populated with all of your exception words.